# How to generate a link with multiple parameters in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a controller method that looks like

```
public ViewResult Index(string id, string participant="", string flagged = "")
```

`id` is a route value in my global.asax for this controller. I want to pass in the other values as regular arguments so the link would look like

```
.../controller/Index/id?participant=yes&flagged=no
```

Is there a way to generate a link like this using Razor script in MVC 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass all parameters in the `routeValues` argument of the ActionLink method:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "go to index",                  // linkText
    "index",                        // actionName
    new {                           // routeValues
        id = "123", 
        participant = "yes", 
        flagged = "no" 
    }
)
```

Assuming default routing setup this will generate:

```
<a href="/Home/index/123?participant=yes&amp;flagged=yes">go to index</a>
```

---

UPDATE:

To further elaborate on the comment you have posted, if the ActionLink generated an url with `Length=6` for example this means that you have used the wrong overload. For example this is **wrong**:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "go to index",             // linkText
    "index",                   // actionName
    "home",                    // routeValues
    new {                      // htmlAttributes
        id = "123", 
        participant = "yes", 
        flagged = "no" 
    }
)
```

It is obvious why this is wrong from the comments I've put along each parameter name. So make sure you are carefully reading the Intellisense (if you are lucky enough to have Intellisense working in Razor :-)) to pick the correct overload of the helper methods.

The correct overload in the case you want to specify a controller name is the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "go to index",             // linkText
    "index",                   // actionName
    "home",                    // controllerName
    new {                      // routeValues
        id = "123", 
        participant = "yes", 
        flagged = "no" 
    },
    null                       // htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice the `null` that is passed as last argument. That's what corresponds to the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this already and for some reason it was giving me a parameter of Length=6 but it worked.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov has answered my simple question once again....and gave details to his answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an ActionLink for this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title",
                 "ActionName", 
                  new {id = 1, participant = "yes", flagged = "no"})
```